# What spells with material costs or permanent effects could the Warlock: The Genie's Limited Wish ability apply to?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

I'm looking for ways to take the most advantage of this new ability from the upcoming *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*:

> You entreat your patron to grant you a small wish. As an action, you can speak your desire to your Genie’s Vessel, requesting the effect of one spell that is 6th level or lower and has a casting time of 1 action. The spell can be from any class’s spell list, and you don’t need to meet the requirements in that spell, including costly components; the spell simply takes effect as part of this action. Once you use this feature, you can’t use it again until you finish 1d4 long rests.

Most of the spells with material costs or permanent/"until dispelled" effects I've come across either have a cast time longer than 1 action, or  are level 7 or higher.  So far the only spells I've found are [Revivify](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Revivify#content) and [Continual Flame](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Continual%20Flame#content). What else am I missing?

Comment: I was not able to find the original source for the genie subclass  preview, only this one (https://www.dropbox.com/s/bshnqiltnttp0gv/TashasPreview_Warlock.pdf?dl=0), and was unsure if this was an appropriate source to link in the question.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this may be  better served split into 2 questions, one for material components, and one for permanent durations. Please advise!

Comment: [The UA Genie is on DnDBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheGenieUA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is somewhat subjective so instead of answering with a list of spells instead I will suggest some tools.

DnDBeyond let's you search spells by level, by action length, and by whether they have a material cost. You can use this to try and find spells that have large material cost components that you find valuable.

For duration, most sites don't seem to be very helpful here but if you look at the player's handbook on DnDBeyond you can also search the page for duration "Until Dispelled" or similar to see all options that way.

One spell I found this way that may be of interest to you:
• Major Image (Read the "At Higher Levels" section)